# Dropdown Navbar - responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

does someone know how I can make my dropdown navbar responsive.

It's hard to explain what I mean, but you notice it if you check it out. Please resize you browser to notice it.

---

If you make your browser smaller you see:
HOME(active), discography & special, I only wish to see the ACTIVE left.

If you open the menu. You see "HIDEKI solo" next to discography.
But I want "HIDEKI solo" below discography. Same goes for SPECIAL!!! & Movie.

> https://codepen.io/Nagashiwa/pen/xxRWwzO

Thank you!

Comment: Could you please try to explain what is the expected behaviour that you want to achieve?

Comment: If you make your browser smaller you see
HOME(active), discography & special,
I only wish to see the ACTIVE left.  

If you open the menu.
You see "HIDEKI solo" next to discography. But I want  "HIDEKI solo"  below discography.
Same goes for SPECIAL!!! & Movie.

Comment: @AlbaHerrerías I hope it's understandable